# New Cart and Quote default shipping method and collect shipping rates flag

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout, magento-1.7

I've set up a custom shipper, called `companyname_customrate` and would like every sales cart / quote created to automatically be assigned this shipping method, as well as have the collect_shipping_rates flag be set to true.

How can I make Magento automatically set these two fields for every cart / quote and make sure that nothing else can change them?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Suggest use an autoquote extn for this, I believe there is a free one available that has been around some time and is widely used.

Comment: This one? https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/5380784 (looks good to me)

Answer (score 0):

Low tech solution: Disable all other shipping methods